# List.add() repeats the same value "n" times controller

Tags: visualforce, controller

This code below in my controller gives the same task 'n' times in the list. Am I missing any pointer reference here ?

```
try {
            listrecurringtaskWrapper= new List<Recurringwrappertask>();
            for (Account a: acct) {

                if (selectedactivitytype == 'Task') {
                    Task newtask = new task();
                    newtask=task; // from the page input fields
                    newtask.whatid=a.id;
                    system.debug('newtask-->'+newtask);
                    system.debug('newtaskwhatid-->'+newtask.whatid);
                    listrecurringtaskWrapper.add(new Recurringwrappertask(newtask));
                    system.debug('listrecurringtaskWrapper2-->'+listrecurringtaskWrapper);
                }


            }
```

Comment: can you explain with more details like what you expect from your code and what issue you facing?

Comment: I have a list view button to select the accounts and create tasks on bulk for the selected account. Here I am trying to map the values from the task ( vf page input field values) to the new tasks for each account selected. The list is giving me the same value n times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
Task newtask = new task();
newtask=task; // from the page input fields
```

You're not copying *fields* from `task` to `newtask` here; you're assigning the same object instance. When you're finished, `listrecurringtaskWrapper` will contain the same object N times.

Instead, copy specific fields from `task` to `newtask`, or use the [`clone()` method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) to copy the instance.

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)